# UTF-8 native locale for ansi-term

Tags: ansi-term, ssh

When I try to connect to a remote machine from an `ansi-term` terminal using [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/) (a remote terminal application), I get the following:

```
$ mosh -- user@host.domain

mosh-server needs a UTF-8 native locale to run.

Unfortunately, the local environment (LC_CTYPE=) specifies
the character set "US-ASCII",

The client-supplied environment (LC_CTYPE=) specifies
the character set "US-ASCII".

LANG=
LC_CTYPE=
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
Connection to user@host.domain closed.
/usr/local/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message.
```

I don't have this problem from `iTerm2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTerm2 and Terminal.app automatically set `LANG` and `LC_*` from the global language settings of OS X.  For instance, if your OS X installation is configured for US language a shell in iTerm2 and Terminal.app automatically receives `LANG=en_US.utf8` in its environment.

Emacs' `ansi-term` however does not do this.  Hence you need to explicitly configure your language environment in the initialisation file of your shell.  For Zsh for instance you would add the following to `~/.zshenv`:

```
if [[ -z $LANG ]]; then export LANG=en_US.utf8; fi
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but this is interestingly making `ansi-term` much slower (e.g. scrolling and rendering of text) when I connect. I am using "GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, NS apple-appkit-1344.72)" from `brew` on a modern MacBook. Not sure how much that matters.

Comment: Does it slow down for ASCII-only text as well, or just for non-ASCII text?

Comment: Regular ASCI-text (e.g. ls a directory with an only-ASCII prompt and contents with ASCII-only characters )